# How can the different elements of the list be multiplied (str and int)?

Tags: python, list, multiplication

I am trying to get conversion of string like 'a3b4' to 'aaabbbb'.
How can this be done without additional modules? So far my code looks like this:

```
s = 'a3b4'
n = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
a = []
b = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] in n:
        a.append(s[i])
    if s[i] not in n:
        b.append(s[i])
for i in range(len(b)):
    print(b[i])
```

Comment: #psuedocode for i in range len(s) new_string =new_string +s[i-1]+s[i-1]*s[i+1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
letters = list(s[::2])
nums = list(s[1::2])
res = ''.join([a*int(b) for a,b in zip(letters,nums)])

>>res
Out[1]: 'aaabbbb'
```

EDIT:

If you want to match any srting and any digits you should use regex:

```
letters = re.findall(r'[a-z]+',s)
nums = re.findall(r'\d+',s)
res = ''.join([a*int(b) for a,b in zip(letters,nums)])
```

for:

```
 s='a10b3'
```

output is:

```
>>res
Out[2]: 'aaaaaaaaaabbb'
```

Comment: Yes, what if number are > 10?

Comment: @NikitaSharov I edited the answer for cases when number>=10.

Comment: @BinyaminEven one more quesion, how could we save an input register? I mean if we have A3b5q1E3 how could we get AAAbbbbbqEEE. Which module we need to use?

Comment: oh, i find it [A-Za-z]